# Where to get the error/info logs of what happens when committing several statements?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, index-tuning, slow-log

I had a problem with an index missing on a table and the only way I had to gather clues was this way:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
-- OVER 100 DELETES
COMMIT;
```

In DBeaver, I selected only the first line and the subsequent deletes, executed that. Then, selected the commit line, executed that and waited until I felt that this is taking too long.

Then DBeaver gave me this message, when I canceled the transaction:

```
SQL Error [57014]: ERROR: canceling statement due to user request
  Where: SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "schema"."table" x WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "id_model" AND $2 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "id_property1" AND $3 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "id_property2" FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
```

`id_model` is the WHERE clause for all the DELETEs in question. The query mentioned in the message is definitely not code written by me, anywhere in any function/procedure/trigger I can think of.

I took from this that a missing index on `table` with columns `id_property1` and `id_property2` was the problem, and apparently it was.

Are there any logs explaining what is happening "under the hood" when the server is processing several statements queued in the transaction where I could have more easily found that statement?

There are several delete foreign key constraints configured in the model, so I guess when indexes are missing, the server is taking a while to find the correct way around?

Comment: That is not a message, it is a nested SQL statement executed by a trigger function that implements a foreign key constraint. It would be interesting to know what exactly the message looked like.

Comment: I posted the complete message. What I'm lookin for is a way to spot these statements somewhere in logs so I don't have to do it in an awkward way through DBeaver or any other DB tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange statement you see was run from a trigger that implements foreign key constraints in PostgreSQL.

There are two ways to get data about these statements:

1. If you set `shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'` and `pg_stat_statements.track = all` and restart PostgreSQL, [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html) will collect statistics about these "hidden" statements as well. You can view these data with the `pg_stat_statements` view provided by the extension of the same name.
2. If you set `shared_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'` and `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on` and `auto_explain.log_min_duration = '500ms'` and restart PostgreSQL, you will get the execution plan of all statements that run for more than half a second logged, including these "hidden" statements.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on DBeaver. It's a generic client, not optimized for Postgres. I have seen occasional complaints about frictions here on dba.SE and SO.

It's the responsibility of the client to show messages (`ERROR`, `WARNING`, `NOTICE`, ...) for each command. Not sure how DBeaver handles that. Maybe you have to execute each `DELETE` separately (still staying within the same transaction) to see all messages.

You can tweak the Postgres settings [`client_min_messages`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES) and [`log_min_messages`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-MESSAGES) to adjust the message levels that are sent to the client and DB log respectively.

But the `SELECT` statement you display is not a "message". It's a plain SQL command. Either you or your client must have issued it. The uncommonly explicit syntax (`OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=)` instead of just `=`) indicates machine-generated code. Maybe it was part of a bigger message displaying what the cancelled query had been waiting for. If a missing index causes one particular statement to dominate execution time, chances to catch that red-handed are good when interrupting execution. It's still coincidence.

Also, while a qualifying index can speed up SQL commands (a lot), a "missing" index is not an error condition (or condition for any message level). You won't get a message from Postgres. Creating indexes happens at the user's discretion. Creating just the right ones is one of the main tasks of the DB architect / administrator. There are countless subtleties to this. Target columns of FK constraints are indexed by definition (a PK or UNIQUE constraint is required). Source columns of FK constraints are prime candidates for a plain B-tree index. Or, as [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) puts it:

> A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or
> form a unique constraint. This means that the referenced columns
> always have an index (the one underlying the primary key or unique
> constraint); so checks on whether a referencing row has a match will
> be efficient. Since a `DELETE` of a row from the referenced table or
> an `UPDATE` of a referenced column will require a scan of the
> referencing table for rows matching the old value, it is often a good
> idea to index the referencing columns too. Because this is not always
> needed, and there are many choices available on how to index,
> declaration of a foreign key constraint does not automatically create
> an index on the referencing columns.

Monitor slow queries to get indication (not proof) for the most pressing missing optimizations. There are various ways, most prominently: set [`log_min_duration_statement`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT) or possibly [`log_min_duration_sample`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-SAMPLE) and friends, and then study the generated DB logs.

And/or use [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) (and all its features) to diagnose suspicious execution plans.